# Passing Model with PagedList.MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, pagedlist

I am using PagedList.MVC for paging in my project. Now I want to pass model to action method when user clicks on the next or any other page no. I tried using :

```
 @Html.PagedListPager(Model.ProductList, page => Url.Action("FilterData", new {page,Model}),PagedListRenderOptions.MinimalWithItemCountText)
```

But the model is not showing any values in my action method. Any idea what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks